# How to access values of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var testarray = [];
var test1 = "ashutosh";
var test2 = "ashutosh2";

if (test1 != test2) {
  testarray.push = "ashutosh3";
  testarray.push = "ashutosh4";
  alert(testarray.length);
}

if (testarray.length != 1) {
  alert(testarray.length);
  alert(testarray[testarray.length - 1]);
  alert(testarray[testarray.length - 2]);
}
```

But when all the alerts are showing up `undefined`. I have no clue why is this happening.

Comment: use browser console to look at errors, above should be throwing error

Comment: @charlietfl: No, it wouldn't.

Comment: @charlietfl: Expanding on Felix's comment: You can assign to an array's `push` property. What that does is create a property on the array instance, shadowing (hiding) the one it inherits from its prototype. So it doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do what the OP wants. Even the bit at the end where the OP will be accessing array entries `-1` and `-2` (because `array.length` will be `0`) is fine, those properties don't exist, and so the result of looking them up is the value `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks.. guess I should have tested myself...property concept makes sense though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) is a *function*, not a property, so instead of

```
testarray.push="ashutosh3";
```

it's

```
testarray.push("ashutosh3");
```

Here's how I'd update that code, FWIW, but I think the only *substantive* change is doing the `push` correctly and using `>= 2` rather than `!= 1` in the `length` check at the end (since otherwise if the array is empty you're looking at entries `-1` and `-2`, which will be undefined):

```
var testarray = [];
var test1 = "ashutosh";
var test2 = "ashutosh2";

if (test1 !== test2) {
  testarray.push("ashutosh3");
  testarray.push("ashutosh4");
  alert(testarray.length);
}

if(testarray.length >= 2) {
  alert(testarray.length);
  alert(testarray[testarray.length-1]);
  alert(testarray[testarray.length-2]);  
}
```

Comment: And the test `!(test1 == test2)` would make more sense as `test1 != test2`

Comment: @NULL: Indeed. Or at least, it would to me, 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder already answer the issue with push but I'm guessing you are new to JavaScript so here are some useful tips I wished knew earlier.

**For Each Loops**

Instead of writing a standard for loop, you can use a forEach loop.

```
for( i in testArray ){
    console.log( i );
}
```

**Objects**

Till hashtables and modules make their appearance to JS, we are left with using arrays.  Here is the easiest method I know of to make an object.

```
var ArrayUtils = {
    "print" : function(array) {
        console.log(array);
    }
}
```

Since ArrayUtils is an list, you can extend it using either dot or bracket notation

```
ArrayUtils["size"] = function(array){
   return array.length;
}

ArrayUtils.indexOf = function(array, i){
    return array[i];
}
```

**Higher-Order Functions**

Arrays in JavaScript come with a built-in map, reduce and filter functions.  These three functions are highly useful when it comes to writing elegant code.

1. Map, passes each element in an sequence into a function

   ```
   testArray.map( function(i){ console.log(i); } );
   ```
2. Reduce, well reduces the array into a single value.  In this example i'm calculating the sum of the array

   ```
   testArray.reduce( function(x,y) { return x+y; } );
   ```
3. Filter, as you could guess removes elements from an array.  In JS, .filter() returns a new array

   ```
   testArray = testArray.filter( function(i) { return ( i > 0 ); } );
   ```

I also read that JS has iterator and generator support.  They are powerful iteration tools and worth checking out if you are going to heavily use iteration in your code base.  I don't so, it's been something I put off as a todo.